How to migrate Dynamics CRM emails and attachments via SSIS?
I am attempting to migrate an on-prem Dynamics CRM to the cloud version using Integration Services.  Most of the entities have been straightforward - I create a copy of the table, update any fields that need updating (for example, update the OwnerID field to match the cloud guid for that user, etc).  Then, using Kingswaysoft in Visual Studio, I push the staging table up to the cloud CRM.  However, now we are trying to migrate attachments and emails and keep running into issues.  Note - I am a SQL developer not a CRM admin, so I don't have a great grasp of where this information is stored (Emailbase, ActivityMimeAttachment, Attachment, FileAttachmentBase, ActivityPartyBase).  I suspect the order of migration is probably key to this process, but have been unsuccessful in finding a guide that explains this.
Can anyone enlighten me?
Have received a variety of errors, depending upon which entity I try migrating first:

the 'create' method does not support entities of type 'activitypointer'
error identified in Payload provided by the user for Entity:'emails'
entity 'email' with id= does not exist


I would highly recommend checking the following package - http://www.kingswaysoft.com/downloads/samples/CrmMigrationStarterPack.zip
I contains the OOB entities import from ground to cloud so it could give you a good clue on how to map entities and fields.
